# Redirect the user to a specific page after signIn

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Main issue is checking if user has a child in the Firebase database so that I know if he is signing up or logging in.

Part 1: Part 1 (Child Database (this works) and making that a user default (I'm not sure how to check it that worked)

Part 2: in different .Swift file (Check if the User Default (aka Education Child) exists. I have pretty much nothing, except I know it must go into viewDidAppear

Part 1

```
@IBAction func SubmitPressed(_ sender: Any) {             
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()             
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
databaseRef.child("Education").child(uid).setValue(self.Education.text!)             
UserDefaults.standard.set("Education", forKey: "Education")
```

Part 2
    func viewDidAppear(_ animated: String) {
    ?????? 
}

No error for part 1, though not sure if it created the user default. For part 2, I have tried a bunch of stuff, but hasn't worked.

Here is the updated code after first answer:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import Firebase
import CoreFoundation
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseDatabase


var educationCache : String {
    get {
        return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Education")!)
    } set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "Education")
    }
}
```

## relavant part of education/personal info enter page

```
@IBAction func SubmitPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    databaseRef.child("Education").child(uid).setValue(self.Education.text!)
    // The following line will save it in userDefault itself. And you dont have to call the whole UserDefault Everywhere
    educationCache = "Education"

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
         }
```

## homepage

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import Firebase
import CoreFoundation
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseDatabase




class homepage:UITableViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if educationCache.count < 0 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
    }

    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {



  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signOut))
   super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@objc func signOut (_sender: AnyObject) {


    KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

     }

 }
```

Comment: So do you want to see the current user exists and then sign him up or are you looking for a separate child and if that exist, you will signup the current user. Can you be a little clear and specific so I can help you

Comment: Posted the answer. Let me know if that works for you. And if it does please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes logical sense, I don't know why it is not working. I suppose you are talking about animated not animted in the last part? It says there is extra animted or animated in the super .viewDidAppear part.

Comment: To summarize better what I have: 1 login/registration page, then a page that lets users enter education and other personal info, and then a homepage. So, I am checking if the user has already completed the education/personal info page and sending him straight from login/registration to homepage if that is the case. If he is registering (ie has no education/personal info in firebase database) I am sending him from login/register to the education/personal info page before he can get to homepage. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you help me with what part is exactly not working?

Comment: So it is running if I use super.viewDidApprear(animated), but it is going straight from login/registration page to homepage even though it is a user who has not completed the education/personal info form. This is how I have my last part: func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if educationCache.count <= 1 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }
        
    }

Comment: why are you doing `educationCache.count <= 1`. education.count will give the amount of data consumed. It doesnt hold any specific int value

Comment: My bad, I just tried 1 because 0 didn't work. Should <= 0 look at data consumed if everything else is correct? I had it 0 to begin with but it also didn't work.

Comment: data < 0, Means data is nil. And data>0 means data is there. Check if that works

Comment: Do you mean: if educationCache.count < 0? That doesn't work.

Comment: If the answer worked for you. Please close the question by accepting the answer

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It didn't work, but I will accept it. You helped a lot. The answer from yesterday was closer to working, just the last if statement that failed. But thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. I am sure this answer should work for sure and will be more efficient. If you want to share your sample repo on github I can take a look. Cheers man

Comment: Thanks. The reason I think the previous approach is better is once all this is done and the user is using the app, say he wants to change his education entry again. Then it would make sense that it was made as a user default upon registration, so that he can now change it by clicking on a settings outlet.

Comment: Anyway, if you'd like to look at it in Github, here it is: https://github.com/carlo190101martin/WP/tree/master/WestPluto1

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hey, just checking if I posted to GitHub correctly? It is the first time I've posted there. Sigh, I still haven't been able to solve this problem.

Comment: Hey, sorry have been completely stacked up with work. Let me take a look this evening. I'll try to help :)

Comment: Hey, no problem. Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it :) I have to do more learning of the basics to get this stuff right. I've been trying to use snapshot as well. Anyway, I don't wanna interfere with your work. Spotmi look cool.

Comment: Thanks man. I have been there in earlier year of my programming. i'll definitely try to help. Please keep that repo hosted. And thanks for taking a look. Startups consume plenty of time, hence late response

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep it open. Yeah, I can imagine startups being extremely time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to check the condition is the viewController where you are performing specific actions. Also checking the userDefaults everytime is just putting extra views in heirarchy. Firebase provides `.addStateDidChangeListener` function to keep a check of it. Add the following code to your delegate. It will automatically switch between the users if there are any or not.

```
AppDelegate.swift

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        observeUser()
        return true
    }

    func observeUser(){
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if (user != nil) {
                // If the user is not nil. Perform this block
                self.showInitController(with identifier: "<add_your_storyboard_reusableID_for_homepage>", animated: false)
                // The storyboard Id belongs to the HOMEPAGE/FEED, the view where user goes on signIn
            } else {
                //If there is no user. This block will perform
                self.showInitController(with identifier: "<add_your_storyboard_reusableID_for_loginpage>", animated: false)
                // The storyboard Id belongs to the SIGNUP PAGE, the view where user goes on signIn
            }
        }
    }

   func showInitController(with identifier: String, animated: Bool = false) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
            var topRootViewController: UIViewController = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
            while((topRootViewController.presentedViewController) != nil){
                topRootViewController = topRootViewController.presentedViewController!
            }
            topRootViewController.present(vc, animated: animated, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

In your swift file one. do the following and never look back. You can automatically redirect to view if you applied the other functions.

```
@IBAction func SubmitPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        databaseRef.child("Education").child(uid).setValue(self.Education.text!)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)
    }
```

In the second view dont bother to do anything anywhere. Just leave it, if nothing in that view is required again.

Comment: I think I am getting closer. Right now here is what I have for the last step:  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if educationCache.count < 0 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }
        
    }        ------------------ I thought the super is enough for override, but maybe I need to add the override. Then only issue is back at step 1, there is an error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @user9269956 what was nil? Can you paste the code from bothe swift files in the question

Comment: This line gave the error: return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Education")!). Yeah, I will paste the full code now.

Comment: Code has been updated in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Buddy You have done it completely wrong. viewDidAppear should have super.viewDidAppear. Secondly, You why are you doing .count < 0. Look what have I done in the answer

Comment: Thanks. I had super.viewDidAppear, then later tried super.viewWillAppear. They both didn't work. I did .count < 0 instead of .count > 0 because in the case that the user didn't fill out the education field (> 0 means he did), he needs to be directed to the fill out page via self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve in the viewDidAppear? Can you write the exact work flow in the bullet points or some pseudo code. I can sense some issue in the architecture.

Comment: Are you trying to sign in the user and then when he opens app again you want to take him to home rather than registration page?

Comment: "Are you trying to sign in the user and then when he opens app again you want to take him to home rather than registration page?" – Yes exactly. When he signs in the first time(he needs to be redirected via the self.performSegue to the page where he can enter his info. Then all other times, he foes straight to homepage.

Comment: are you using storyboards or initializing programmatically ?

Comment: Here is a breakdown of the function line by line: 
     func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if educationCache.count > 0 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }

Comment: 1st line - This is the function for a Boolean to see if the user does not have a education user default (ie has not entered personal info, ie is registering not logging in)

2nd line - I got this from your answer. From what I gather super has some overriding purpose. The (animated: animated) didn’t work; Xcode said one one can be there.

3rd Lin - Check if the user DOES NOT HAVE a education child database entry in firebase/ user default (ie he is registering not logging in)

Comment: 4th line - Because he is registering (does not have education child entry in firebase database/user default) send him to page where he can enter that information

Comment: Wait. I know what exactly you are doing. Just tell me are you using storyboard. The way you are implementing the code is actually wrong. I am updating my answer

Comment: "are you using storyboards or initializing programmatically ? " - Uhm more programmatically than storyboard. What I have in storyboard is mainly naming the identifier toFeed that links the homepage to the education info filling page. Other than that I use storyboard to add buttons, UI text fields.

Comment: So you are using storyboards to init your application or are you using the code. that's what I am asking

Comment: "So you are using storyboards to init your application or are you using the code. that's what I am asking" Uhm, I am not 100% sure, but I only have the tweaked AppDelegate.swift file other than these ones. I checked "is initial view controller" in Storyboard for the login/registration page.

Comment: I'll check. Thank you!